# Error in tkinter when using subprocess function

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I'm trying to call a Python script through subprocess. The problem is that this action is launched through a function by clicking a button, and the GUI stops responding.

```py
... Window code
        ''' BUTTON EXEC '''
        button_exec = tk.Button(self, text="Ejecutar", fg='black', bg='green',
                            command=self.generate_reporting_ger)
        button_exec.place(x=50, y=500, width=100, height=60)  

... Button code function
    def generate_reporting_ger(self):
        top = tk.Toplevel()
        top.focus_force()
        top.title("Ejecutando...")

        msg = tk.Message(top, text="Ejecutando calidad e integridad de GER, espere a que genere los resultados")
        msg.pack()

        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(path + "GER_script.bat", bufsize=2048, shell=True,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            p.wait()
        except:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Error en la ejecución", "No se ha generado el reporting del sistema")
            top.destroy()
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Ejecución terminada", "Se ha generado el reporting del sistema")
```

Comment: open the script in a new thread/process as per your usage

Comment: What do you mean?